Flutter Native Splash Screen package causing the app not to run in the android emulator
I'm trying to add a Splash Screen to my flutter app, but when I add the "flutter_native_splash" dependency to my pubspec.yaml file, I cannot run the android emulator. When I press "Start Debugging", nothing happens.
The debug console just prints "Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode..." and then its stops the launch process. I tried to add other packages to my pubspec.yaml file, and it works fine with others.
Also, I checked the Flutter Doctor. Everything seems fine. Tried flutter clean and also nothing changed. I can't run my app in the emulator when this dependency in my pubspec.yaml file.

Please share you file where you added code for launch icon.

The launch icon is on the "images" folder. But i think thats not the problem. Because when i run the package command (dart run flutter_native_splash:create) its work fine and completes its work. Also i tried running that command while package is in the pubspec.yaml file, and then removing the dependency. It worked, the splash screen works without this dependency. But i dont want to add and remove it everytime, and also i want to learn whats the problem.

Step 1: Add image splash with path: assets/images/img_splash.png 
Step 2: Declare splash image in pubspec.yaml 
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/locales/
    - assets/images/

flutter_native_splash:
  image: assets/images/img_splash.png
  color: "0084FF"
  fill: true

Step 3: Run command dart run flutter_native_splash:create in Terminal at root project
Hope it helps!

Hey, thanks for the answer. But this is didn't work either. Its still not launching while splash screen package in the dependencies.

You can try adding flutter_native_splash with the command in the terminal flutter pub add flutter_native_splash. In some cases tried deleting pubspec.lock, .flutter-plugins, .flutter-plugins-dependencies then running flutter pub get command and rebuilding and it works. You can try it.

Also this is didnt work. The app is still not launching.
